# How to keep then rename file with certain condition and running loop in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

May I ask your help. I want to clean file in R environment. The file will named like T1-T1_R1.fastq, T1-T1_R2.fastq, T1-T2_R1.fastq, T1-T2_R2.fastq, ect. I just want to keep file with similar character before and after "-/dash", eg. T1-T1 the rename it to T1_R1.fastq and T1_R2.fastq. While the file with different character before and after "-" will be deleted.

Thank you for your kind help and attention.

Screenshot on the list of files:

[image]

I expected to keep file based on criteria where string before and after "-" then renamed it. Other files need to delete.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `file.rename` - get the file names from the folder, modify the file name by removing the prefix till the `-` using `sub`, and use `file.rename` to rename those

```
path <- "<path/to/your/folder>"
# get all the names of .fastq files
files <- list.files(path, pattern = "\\.fastq", full.names = TRUE)
# extract the basename
filenms <- basename(files)
create a logical vector where it matches the prefix, suffix from `-`
i1 <- sub("(\\w+)-.*", "\\1",filenms) == 
          sub(".*-(\\w+)_.*", "\\1", filenms)
# subset the files to keep
files_to_keep <- filenms[i1]
# remove all the rest of the files
file.remove(files[!i1])
new_files <- file.path(path, sub(".*-", "", files_to_keep))
# rename those files
file.rename(from = files[i1], to = new_files)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't want to keep them all. I just want to keep file that named similar code between ID1 and ID2. This the generic name "ID1-ID2_R1.fastq". So file with different ID will be removed, such as T4-T9_R1.fastq and keep the file of T4-T4_R1.fastq the rename it to T4_R1.fastq. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndhikaPrasetyo In that case you may want to use `file.remove` first and then on the subset you want to rename

Comment: Thank Akrun, it works. Just missed n in line 4 for filems. Thanks again for your kindness.

Comment: Dear Akrun,
There is still missing part where I need to rename selected files to simplified name. Such as "T4-T4_R1.fastq" to "T4_R1.fastq". Thank you

Comment: @AndhikaPrasetyo sorry, it was there in the original solution, i might have accidentally removed it.  Please check the update